# Push notification phonegap android doesn't work after device restart

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an app on phonegap-Android with push notifications using GCM. it works perfectly.But The problem is when I reset phone- notifications dont come. Do have any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing app ? because i don't think this is PhoneGap issue

Comment: Yes I have re-installed the application more than once.
Each time the device receives the notification correctly,
but after restart device notifications dont come